# Step in the proof (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

Tags: real-analysis

I am unsure on a specific step in a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vFlj.png). How do we know that if there exists a delta fine partition of I, that F(b) - F(a) equals the sum of the integral of the delta fine partition. Also, how doe we know that |F(b) - F(a) - S(f,P)| equals what comes after it? I have been able to follow the proof until this point. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would be better to make your question self-contained. In order to deal with your question, we have to keep going back and forth between your link and typing here; it's a pain. Make the effort to type out the equation(s) that you have specific questions about. I don't even understand where your first question comes from. The proof you've linked merely asserts $$F(b)-F(a) = \sum F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})$$ by telescoping. Your next question seems to be combining that with the definition of the Riemann sum (and combining the two summations).

Answer (score 1):

Since $a=x_0$ and $b=x_n$,\begin{align}F(b)-F(a)&=F(x_n)-F(x_0)\\&=F(x_n)-F(x_{n-1})+F(x_{n-1})-F(x_{n-2})+\cdots-F(x_1)+F(x_0)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})\bigr).\end{align}And, since$$S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$and since$$F(b)-F(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})\bigr),$$you have$$F(b)-F(a)-S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})-t_i(x_i-x_{i-1})\bigr).$$